# What kind of data is suited for xsd:QName?

Tags: wsdl

For example the `xsd:string` datatype is suite for String data. Which kind of data is suited for the `xsd:QName` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a string like `xsd:string` would be appropriate.

Comment: My problem is that the data which the webservice sends contains accentuated letters such as `é` ; and the client program receives exception ! So how to make the webservice supports accentuated letters ?